# Help identifying D1047 transistor (pic included)

Tags: transistors

Who can help me identify this transistor?

It came out of a Chinese micromotor power supply.

Text on top is "D1047 905".

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/r0ib8ikionm7ctu/Photo%20Aug%2022%2C%2010%2055%2028%20AM%20%28HDR%29.jpg]

Can I substitute it with other transistor?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a datasheet for a [2SD1047](http://datasheet.seekic.com/PdfFile/D10/D1047.pdf), which will almost certainly be for this device.

Searching for "D1047 datasheet" finds a few more similar datasheets, it's a NPN power transistor. Certainly replaceable with a similar component from e.g. Farnell, Digikey, etc - they will have many options.

Of course, you can always order an [exact replacement](http://www.alibaba.com/product-gs/629513340/Transistor_D1047_New_and_Original_Electronic.html?s=p) if you should wish.

Comment: Even the angled top of the plastic part of the tab is right... Yup, looks like it all right.

Answer (score 1):

Pinout and spec sheet - NPN 140V, 12A

[image]

[image]